# Iterating through 2 dynamic lists

Tags: c#, wpf, list, iteration

I'm in the middle of creating a piece of software for the company that I have internship at, now I'm having some trouble iterating through 2 dynamic lists.

The first list is a list of grids (WPF) and the other one is list of Column Definitions (WPF) I'd like to add 3 columns to each grid in the GridList, but I'm not quite sure on how I'd go about doing so.

If you need some code examples then I'll happily add  them, but I don't see it nessecary for this kind of question.

When I say Dynamic List, I mean a list that doesn't have a set size, so in my case it depends on which day it is.

Comment: `var grids = new List<Grid> { new Grid(), new Grid(), new Grid() };    foreach (var grid in grids) grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());`

Comment: Thank you, I overthought this way to much I think.

Comment: You're welcome! @MohammedNoureldin posted *same* answer )

Comment: I do not like the name of the question, could you rename it to something more meaningful? cuz it just confuses the people who are looking for something else.

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin you're welcome to come with a name suggestion that makes more sense to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an Object of list, and add your grids to it:

```
var grids = new List<Grid> 
{ 
    new Grid(),
    new Grid(),
    new Grid() 
};
```

Iterate through the grids and add what you want to them:

```
foreach (var grid in grids)
{
    grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
}
```